# Xampp recover DB

Tags: php, server, phpmyadmin, xampp, localhost

So basically today I uninstalled xampp and didn't realised that I deleted my database. I was supposed to reinstall xampp. Luckily I got my old files back via ShadowExplorer but other problem came with old database files. When I import them back to .../xam/mysql/data/ directory it showes me that : [Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjRf2.png)

Also here is my folder : [Database folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vjDJ.png)

I'm guessing that I forgot to make some additional changes

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You will get better answers if you explain what you have already tried, and provide a clear question.

Answer (score 0):

Install same version of XAMPP (Don't use new version or another version.)

Create a folder into `xampp/mysql/data` ("Old database name" like this `xampp/mysql/data/db_restore`), Copy all files like *.frm + *.ibd & etc into your created folder (`xampp/mysql/data/db_restore`).

Start MySQL.

Connect to your MySQL, Open `db_restore` database, Generate a SQL backup.